# Как в xcode на swift из ячеек сделать переходы на разные ViewController?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

Как в xcode на swift из ячеек сделать переходы на разные ViewController?

Например "Мурка" ссылались бы на ViewController1, "Пушистик" на ViewController2, "Шарик" на ViewController3.

Думаю что через - override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) но не знаю как с ней работать. Помогите!

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var bDays = [
    "Коты": ["Мурка", "Пушистик"],
    "Собаки": ["Шарик", "Песик"],
    "Мыши": ["Маус", "Крыс"]]


struct Objects {  //Вспомогательная структура
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}

var objectArray = [Objects]() // Источник данных

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for (key, value) in bDays {
        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
    }
}


// MARK: - Table view data source


// Получим количество секций в таблице
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return objectArray.count
}


// Получим количество строк для конкретной секции
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}


// Получим заголовок для секции
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectArray[section].sectionName
}


// Получим данные для использования в ячейке
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Вот только не prepare, а perform​Segue(with​Identifier:​sender:​)

Comment: если б еще кода немного)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через кнопку Select Plane (жёлтый круг в верху View) подцепляй сеги и давай им имена, затем переопределяй функцию действия при выделении ячейки:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toData", sender: nil)
}
```

Для возможности перехода на несколько разных контроллеров используй цикл if, в котором будет проверяться либо надпись в лейбле ячейки/другом поле, либо номер ячейки. Соответственно, идентификаторы сегов меняй на свои.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не советовал делать переходы с помощью `Segue`, так как они очень неудобны и представьте сколько будет стрелочек на вашем `storyboard`.
А еще большое количество `identifier`-ов, которые уже своего рода хардкод из-за стрингового формата

Избежать всего этого можно очень просто

для начала создаем extension для вылавливания `UIViewController` по `identifier`.
`identifier` должен быть таким же как и название класса

```
extension UIViewController {
  class var identifier: String {
    return String(describing: self)
  }
}

extension UIStoryboard {
  class func instantiate<T: UIViewController>(storyboardName: String) -> T {
    let identifier = String(describing: T.self)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    guard let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? T else {
      fatalError()
    }
    return viewController
  }
}
```

После этого можно с очень легко *вылавливать* нужный `UIViewController`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let viewController: MyViewController = UIStoryboard.instantiate()
  viewController.parametrs = parametrs
  self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil) // Для modal перехода
}
```

или для перехода `show`

```
self.navigationController?.show(viewController, sender: nil)
```